# if , then command on deb file

Tags: ios, bash, if-statement

I want to create a deb file for iOS. I created 3 command files on debian folder its presint, postint and postrm. Why this code cannot function when I install the deb file?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "/System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji.ttf" ];then
mv /System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji.ttf /System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji.backup

elif [ "/System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji@2x.ttf" ];then
mv /System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji@2x.ttf /System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji@2x.backup

elif [ "/System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji@3x.ttf" ];then
mv /System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji@3x.ttf /System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji@3x.backup

else
     echo "cannot backup font"
fi
```

I want this command able to find what file is inside the dir and remane that file to backup.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ and Lintian are your friends. And it's `preinst` not `presint` or `preints`.

Comment: And you actually want that to execute on your iPhone/iOS device? Is it jailbroken? If it's not jailbroken you just can't do that.

Comment: yupp.. i want that to execute on my iPhone/iOS device.. yes my iphone is jailbroken.. sory for my bad typo.. i m using preinst..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problm solve.. i use this script..

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /System/Library/Font/Cache

Em="AppleColorEmoji.ttf"
Em2="AppleColorEmoji.Backup"

if [ -f "${Em}" ]; then
   mv "${Em}" "${Em2}"
else echo "Searching.."
fi

Em3="AppleColorEmoji@2x.ttf"
Em4="AppleColorEmoji@2x.Backup"

if [ -f "${Em3}" ]; then
  mv "${Em3}" "${Em4}"
else echo "Searching.."
fi

Em5="AppleColorEmoji@3x.ttf"
Em6="AppleColorEmoji@3x.Backup"

if [ -f "${Em5}" ]; then
  mv "${Em5}" "${Em6}"
else echo "Searching.."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the -f flag in the if-statement. The -f flag tests for a file, see `man test` for all possibilities.

I also added some var's to make the code easier to read:

```
#!/bin/bash
orgdir="/System/Library/Fonts/Cache"
# targetdir is here equal to orgdir, maybe you want to change in the future.
targetdir="/System/Library/Fonts/Cache"

# When orgdir or targetdir contains spaces, you need double quotes,
# in this example you do not need them.
# I use the double quotes for good habits

if [ -f "${orgdir}/AppleColorEmoji.ttf" ]; then
   mv "${orgdir}/AppleColorEmoji.ttf" "${targetdir}/AppleColorEmoji.backup"
elif [ -f "${orgdir}/AppleColorEmoji@2x.ttf" ]; then
   mv "${orgdir}/AppleColorEmoji@2x.ttf" "${targetdir}/AppleColorEmoji@2x.backup"
elif [ -f "${orgdir}/AppleColorEmoji@3x.ttf" ]; then
   mv "${orgdir}/AppleColorEmoji@3x.ttf" "${targetdir}/AppleColorEmoji@3x.backup"   
else
     echo "cannot backup font"
fi
```

Comment: Can you do a `chmod 777 /System/Library/Fonts/Cache` ? First see and write somewhere what the original rights are with `ls -l /System/Library/Fonts/Cache`.

Comment: When `mv /System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji.ttf /System/Library/Fonts/Cache/AppleColorEmoji.backup` works, the dir and filename are correct. Try `echo "Hello there"` at the start, and `ls ${orgdir}` before the first if-statement. Does your script has execute rights, what will it say when you start it? Did you see "cannot backup font" or an error message from the mv command?

Comment: hello Walter A..  i m already trying the `echo "Hello There"` and `ls -l /System/Library/Fonts/Cache` but nothing change.. i cannot see the `echo "Hello There" and "Cannot backup font" and no error message from the mv command.. :(

Comment: So it seems the script is no executed at all. Try `chmod 777 yourscript` and check that the last character of the first line is a `h` (not a space, tab or ^M).